# Disable devtools drawer in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Today I just updated my chrome after 1-2 years. Now I have chromium with version 50.14.22.465. When I'm inspecting some elements and something in JavaScript prints error to the console, it will also open chrome's drawer. So it looks like this:

[image]

I know that I can hide it with `ESC` key, but when I refersh website and another error comes to the console, drawer is openned again. How can I turn this off permanently?

And in the newest chrome you cannot disable "Highlighting DOM updates"? Uhh, gross.

Comment: FYI 50 is not the latest, 53 is.

Comment: I know, but I'm using Comodo Dragon on Chromium, where 50 is the latest.